# Stochastic control, numerical, need expectations given coupled SDEs

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance

I'm looking at a trio of processes which arises in a stochastic control situation. I have a process $(V_t)$ which I may control, and $(V_t)$ influences a diffusive stock price process $(S_t)$. The evolution of my wealth function $(W_t)$ depends on both $(V_t)$ and $(S_t)$. Without giving the explicit SDEs, are there any techniques one can evaluate $E[W_t]$ numerically?

Many thanks.

Comment: I see no question here.

Comment: You can run monte-carlo, all other techniques depend on the way $W_t$ is constructed.